# Mongodb driver with mongodb bson library causes completableFuture hangs when used in separate projects

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I have a project, let's say `projectA` which had an HTTP component that exposed it's logic to clients.

Within this project there's code like such:

```
void syncMethod() {
  CompletableFuture<Void> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
  someAsyncOperationThatReceivesACallback((Void x, Exception ex) -> {
    if(ex != null) f.completeExceptionally(ex);
    else f.complete(null); // An example of a result.
  });
  f.get(); // Wait unconditionally 
}
```

And this code works, as in it waits for the completion of the operation and the future is completed with the result of the async operation.

The need arose to share the logic between 2 webapps and so I separated `projectA` into 2 projects, let's say `projectA-LOGIC` and `projectA-HTTP` where `projectA-HTTP.dependsOn(projectA-LOGIC)`

Having the entry point in `projectA-HTTP` and the code above **in the packaged JAR** of `projectA-LOGIC` the code above stopped completing, meaning that the future is never completed and the application just stands there.

If however I create an entry point in `projectA-LOGIC` and run the code above everything works.

I don't understand the magic that is happening here. Currently using `jdk8_111`. The async operation abstracted above comes from the [mongodb async driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver-async/) and is [listCollectionNames](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/). All async (via callback) operation's I attempt to make sync using futures suffer the same behavior when I have 2 projects.

**EDIT:**

Thread dump:

Full thread dump

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1693)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1729)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)

"cluster-ClusterId{value='588bc56a32de912224244114', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017@4072" daemon prio=5 tid=0xf nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:238)
      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:219)
      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:168)
      - locked <0x10fe> (a com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"cluster-588bc56a32de912224244114@4283" daemon prio=5 tid=0x15 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
      at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
      at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster$WaitQueueHandler.run(BaseCluster.java:464)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-6@4227" daemon prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Iocp.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
      at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-5@4225" daemon prio=5 tid=0x13 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Iocp.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
      at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-4@4224" daemon prio=5 tid=0x12 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Iocp.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
      at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-3@4217" daemon prio=5 tid=0x11 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Iocp.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
      at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-2@4216" daemon prio=5 tid=0x10 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Iocp.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
      at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Finalizer@4348" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler@4349" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"Attach Listener@4346" daemon prio=5 tid=0x5 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher@4347" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

What I can't understand is how can this happen just by spliting the code into separate projects. Think I'm missing some subtle detail about CompletableFutures...

Comment: I can't really tell what it could be, but I'd look for a deadlock.  Also check if nothing else is using threads from the common thread pool.  IIRC CompletableFuture use threads from the common pool -- might try using a seperate pool.

Comment: That's what I think to, Added thread dump. But I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: If that's the thread dump, then I don't think any of your code is running at all, those are two JVM threads only.

Comment: @john16384 you're right. In my frustration I tunnel visioned into what I wanted to see. Just posted the full thread dump. I'm working on isolating the problem by creating a new project that has just this code to see if the problem still happens and if I find something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be much simpler and (dumber) that anything I would expect.

I was using the mongodb async driver v3.2.1 and using the mongodb bson library v3.4.1. Turns out that when I changed the version of the bson library to v3.2.1 everything worked fine.